# Storing Chat Messages w/ Redis + Another Database

Tags: database, node.js, redis, chat

I've recently begun working on a realtime chat application as a side project, mainly for experience. The clients will initially only be iOS/Android applications.

For the backend, I'm utilizing NodeJs for two reasons:

- I want to use websockets
- And I've never worked on a project with node before so its good exp

My main question, as the question indicates is regarding the architecture of how I will be storing chat messages on the server.

By reading other posts regarding this topic and researching the internetz I've come up with the following:

1. Client sends message to server to send to another user through sockets
2. Message gets put into Redis(stores last 50 messages for each chat)
3. Message also gets added to a permanent store database(Relational or NoSQL) asynchronously
4. At a later point in time if the user needs to for any reason retrieve the messages for a chat again, he/she gets the 50 messages from Redis(fast) and if he/she scrolls up to see older messages, query the permanent store for next batch of older messages.

I'm in no way an expert on databases but this seemed to be a reasonable/scalable approach to me.

I'm looking for any advice you can regarding reliability/scalability/anything for this architecture that you can give me. I'm happy to provide more info if needed.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any working?

Comment: I haven't implemented it yet. I'm currently in the research phase for the project.

Comment: You could add it to a MySQL database

Comment: Use MySQL as the permanent datastorage in the architecture I described above?

Comment: Use it as permanent storage